# Get List of all the dags in python

Tags: airflow

I have a list of dags that are hosted on Airflow. I want to get the name of the dags in a AWS lambda function so that I can use the names and trigger the dag using experimental API. I am stuck on getting the names of the dag.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you please provide the version of Airflow you're using, and anything you have tried so far.

Comment: The question is how to list dags using python. Unless the question is to fins it via APi or CLI?

Comment: I could not find any endpoint in the Airflow Experimental API (deprecated as of version 2.0) for listing dags (Source: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/deprecated-rest-api-ref.html). There is one endpoint in the stable API which can be found here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dags (I think it's `/api/v1/dags?<query_parameters_here>` but I have not tried it myself). You might also have to configure appropriate authentication settings in `airflow.cfg` before using the API.

Answer (score 10):

```
from airflow.models import DagBag
dag_ids = DagBag(include_examples=False).dag_ids
for id in dag_ids:
   print(id)
```

Comment: thanks - the question specifically asks for Python API and your answer is the only one that actually uses it

Answer (score 8):

Since Airflow 2.0, the `airflow list_dags` command is now:

```
airflow dags list [-h] [-o table, json, yaml, plain] [-S SUBDIR] [-v]
```

with the following named arguments:

`-o`, `--output`

- Possible choices: table, json, yaml, plain
- Output format. Allowed values: json, yaml, plain, table (default:
  table)
- Default: “table”

`-S`, `--subdir`

- File location or directory from which to look for the dag. Defaults to ‘[AIRFLOW_HOME]/dags’ where [AIRFLOW_HOME] is the value you set for ‘AIRFLOW_HOME’ config you set in ‘airflow.cfg’
- Default: “[AIRFLOW_HOME]/dags”

`-v`, `--verbose`

- Make logging output more verbose
- Default: False

See:

- [Airflow CLI changes in 2.0](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-from-1-10/index.html?highlight=list_dags#airflow-cli-changes-in-2-0)
- [Command Line Interface and Environment Variables Reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#list_repeat2)

Answer (score 2):

All Airflow-CLI commands for the various various are listed on this URL - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/usage-cli.html

In the latest version you could do

```
airflow list_dags
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first connect with the backend database, By default airflow using SQLite.
Then you can check the DAGs status from table `dag` using columns `is_active`
and `is_paused`

e.g. `airflow=# SELECT dag_id FROM dag WHERE is_active=TRUE AND is_paused=FALSE;`

Comment: I wish you added some steps on how to connect to the backend database.

Answer (score 0):

This command will shows all DAGS include disabled dags as well

`airflow dag_list`