# how to extract all the scripts present in all dags in airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

We have a requirement where we need to give steps to the client to extract all the airflow dag scripts in thier environment in a single file so that we can analyze it manually.

I got thread wherin we can extract the list of all dag names but our requirment to get the underlying script of all airflow dag present

[Get List of all the dags in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895590/get-list-of-all-the-dags-in-python)

Found couple of ways to extract it :

1. All python scripts which is used in dag will be stored in airflow--project-->dags-->datasets folder where airflow is insatlled.
2. All DAG files will have this import statment "from airflow import DAG",So i have created a unix script to fetch all python files in all sub folders which has this string and put it in a single output file along with file name.

Are these the correct way to do? could you please confirm

Comment: Your goal is to have all dag files in a single file? I'm struggling a bit to understand the issue you're trying to solve. Where do you want the output to be?

Comment: One solution is to ask them to send you an archive containing their code repository.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow REST API provides a simpler way to do that:

1. [Get all dags](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dags)
2. [Get file token for each dag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dag)
3. [Get source code for each file token](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dag_source)